# What are the Rails's ActiveRecord database gems on JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jdbc, jruby

When running rails on [JRUBY](http://jruby.org/), database adapters have two different gems.

1. **Sql Server**:  `sqlserver` gem Vs `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` gem
2. **Mysql**: `jdbcmysql` gem vs  `activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` gem
3. **Sqlite3**: `jdbcsqlite3` gem Vs `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter` gem
4. **Postgresql**: `jdbcpostgresql` gem Vs `activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter` gem
5. **jdbc**: `jdbc` gem vs `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` gem

So question is,
What is the difference between `jdbcpostgresql` and its long form `activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter` gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*jdbcpostgresql* = Java Database Connectivity for postgresql database

*activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter* = a postgresql database adapter for Rails ActiveRecord to allow it to be used with JRuby.

JDBC (Java Database Connectivity)

> ActiveRecord-JDBC-Adapter (AR-JDBC) is a database adapter for Rails'
> ActiveRecord component that can be used with JRuby. It allows use of
> virtually any JDBC-compliant database with your JRuby on Rails
> application.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know the difference but i use the following in rails 3+ apps with jruby and postgres for the Gemfile

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
```

see also the README file - https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter