# Active Record vs JRuby vs JDBC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jdbc, jruby

I am new to Ruby on rails and I've recently created a small accounting application which connects to a sqlite3 database.

At the moment, I am still in development and  I can save new data or update existing records on the database using the activerecord commands in the controller side.

But my questions is regarding JDBC with JRuby:

I am new to java as well and from what I understand, JRuby is made entirely of Java code and is being run on a JVM. And that there are gems that won't work if it is written in C.

If I start using JRuby instead of the MRI, what would be the difference? Will i still be using the active record commands in manipulating records in the database?

If I use JRuby and create a new application, does the JDBC adapters work exactly like an existing gem like sqlite3 to connect the application to the database?

Or I would only need to program the JDBC adapter instead of the controller?

I am a little confused of how it would work and a few information would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

What I mean to ask is, currently my application is working on Ruby on Rails and I am using commands in the controller for example when you are updating existing records like this:

```
@variable = [Table_name].find(:id)
```

then

```
@variable.update_attributes(params[:submit])
```

This commands would update the record using RoR, but if using Rails in JRuby, how would this work? is it the same syntax?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question will get more attention if you had the code example with both frameworks. I would be easier to point differences.

Comment: Oh, I haven't started using JRuby yet as I am still researching on it. I just would like to know the difference between the two, like the syntax when accessing a database. Is it it the same?

Comment: No idea why they marked this question as unclear, it's clear that you are confused but this doesn't mean we can't help you. Switching to JRuby won't change your ruby code except for missing gems. Rails works fine on JRuby which means it's entire basic infrastructure works without any problems: activerecord too. You shouldn't care about the db adapter, I think Rails support all database without a lot of problems right now, even on jruby (if not, just check). You may have problems with ruby C gems, but in that case you won't be able to use them at all (so you won't have them). Comments are short

Comment: Thank you. So most of the syntax would be the same.

But can I ask what the JDBC adapter is for? Do I need to create one to use on a specific db?

Comment: It allows you to connect to ANY database type that JDBC can connect to (a lot): https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter It is transparent once you include it in your application anyway.

Comment: So it is only for creating connections between the application and the database? All the data manipulation is within the application only correct? and what the JDBC does is only send that data to the database in form of an SQL command?

Comment: After a a few hours of research I think the term I was referring to was the Object Relational Mapping.

Does JDBC work like ORM?

Comment: JDBC is the API & driver for Java to access the database. The ORM layer (ActiveRecord) is the same in Rails so that won't change.

Comment: So it is safe to assume that both do the same thing? and the only difference is that in JRuby on Rails, you only use the JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC is the Java API and driver to connect to a database.

Rails uses ActiveRecord as the ORM layer that is between the application and the database.

ActiveRecord will then use the driver specified to generate the SQL statements and migrations.

The calls will be always the same from the application side like you mentioned `@variable = [Table_name].find(:id)`

The difference will appear in the generated SQL statements in the logs and the generated migrations to suit the database driver specified.

Comment: Thank you Hitham.

Though I would like ask, what do you think would be the advantages and disadvantages on both?

Comment: You are going to use both depending on the database server.  for example you might use jdbc-sql-server  for SQLServer or jdbc/sqlite for SQLite

Comment: But still all commands are being coded within the application right? all of it inside the controller/model and not inside the JDBC adapter?

Comment: The only thing you will code is the query using ActiveRecord syntax and migrations that might need to be tweaked for certain servers.  JDBC is going to be behind the scenes. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973929/what-are-the-railss-activerecord-database-gems-on-jruby/15979014#15979014